# How can I create a completely case insensitive check constraint on a column

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I'm trying to write a constraint for a table that only allows a column named "filename" to accept entries that contain '.docx', '.doc', '.pdf', and '.txt.' I'd also like the file extensions to be case insensitive so, '.PDF' and '.pDF' etc, would also be accepted. I've tried this code:

```
ALTER TABLE DOCS ADD CONSTRAINT DOCS_EXTENSION_CHK CHECK(FILENAME IN ('.docx', '.doc', '.pdf', '.txt'));
```

I've tried inserting multiple names for files with different extensions such as, 'RANDOMFILE.doc' and 'FILENAME.PdF' but it's I'm receiving an error for everything.

I need the constraint to also allow the name of the file before the extension to be anything, like 'xxxx.docx'.

If anyone could help me out I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regexp_like()`:

```
ALTER TABLE DOCS ADD CONSTRAINT DOCS_EXTENSION_CHK 
    CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(LOWER(FILENAME), '[.]docx$|[.]doc$|[.]pdf$|[.]txt$'));
```

Or more simply as:

```
ALTER TABLE DOCS ADD CONSTRAINT DOCS_EXTENSION_CHK 
    CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(LOWER(FILENAME), '[.](docx|doc|pdf|txt)$'));
```

Comment: Thank you for the lightning fast reply! That worked perfectly.

Comment: @Gordon: is there an advantage to using the character class `[.]` instead of the escaped character literal `\.`?

Comment: @BobJarvis . . . I find backslashes tricky when passing strings between different applications (sometimes they need to be doubled), so I just tend to find ways to avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression is good. But you could simply use `lower()` and `like()` like below

```
ALTER TABLE DOCS ADD CONSTRAINT DOCS_EXTENSION_CHK
CHECK (
    lower(FILENAME ) LIKE ('%.docx') 
    or lower(FILENAME ) LIKE ('%.doc') 
    or lower(FILENAME ) LIKE ('%.pdf')
    or lower(FILENAME ) LIKE ('%.txt')
);
```